# Problem: no headerValue when list is empty <s:select>

Tags: drop-down-menu, struts2

i am using struts 2

i have a  tag

```
<s:select list="list" headerKey="All"
headerValue="All" multiple="true" name="selectedList"
listKey="id" multiple="false"                                   theme="simple"
listValue="Name" size="20">
</s:select>
```

When the List is empty it shows the "ALL" in the drop down, i dont want the headerValue to come in drop down when the "list"  is empty (list.size==0)
Also i dont want to supply the headerKey and headerValue from server.

any help ??????

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can get the select tag to do this as is.  You might be able to extend the theme to make it do this:

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/extending-themes.html

Comment: Not enough help :( . Do anybody have anything else to advise